# Tomcat Classpath

Tags: tomcat, classpath

when i run the following jsp in my tomcat...

```
<html> 
   <head> 
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head> 
   <body> Before:cp=<%=System.getProperty("java.class.path")%> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

i get this output...

Before:cp=C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.24\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\lib\tools.jar

How can i make C:\Myfolder\project appear here...?How do i set this folder to my tomcat6 class path..

Kaddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit catalina.bat (or .sh) to do that. But if you want to simply put some jars on the classpath, put them to \lib

Edit:
The best way to do it is not to edit catalina.bat itself, but to create setenv.bat next to is and make all the changes to `CLASSPATH` variable you need.

Comment: could you please give me an example of what i need to put in setevn.bat

Comment: try set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;path_to_your_jar_here", or without double quotes

Comment: what you suggested worked for me ...but is there a way of doing a similar thing for running my application using eclipse...